# Favicon not working properly in chrome and in firefox

Tags: favicon

I am using wordpress for my website. I put the favicon.ico file in the wp-content folder and I inserted this code into the header:

`<link href="http://seriousautosport.com/wp-content/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />`

Now the favicon works when I'm on the home page and it works on some other random pages. But not on every page. This happens in Chrome and in Firefox. IE works fine and I know why. But how do I get it to work in Chrome and Firefox?

Help.

Comment: This issue doesn't have anything to do with WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided returns a 404, that seems to be the problem.